# sbt compile tasks with different options

Tags: compilation, sbt

I have a basic sbt project. I want to package two jars with the same source files, but compilation with different options.
So one project, 2 compilations but with different options (scalacOptions) and 2 jars as output. I don't want to execute sbt twice, changing the options.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: This is a non trivial problem using sbt. The most straightforward approach would be to create a new configuration extending compile, and creating a package task within that configuration. It would depend on package in Compile while generating its own package. Overall, not an easy job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With something like this in build.sbt, you can run sbt compile2:package and produce both a jar from the compile config and compile2 config:

```
val Compile2 = config("compile2") extend Compile

inConfig(Compile2)(Defaults.compileSettings ++ Seq(
    // these options can be set as "in Compile2" outside of inConfig as well
    scalacOptions := SECOND-OPTIONS-LIST,
    // otherwise it will be "src/compile2", you want it to be "src/main"
    sourceDirectory <<= sourceDirectory in Compile,
    sbt.Keys.`package` <<= sbt.Keys.`package` dependsOn (sbt.Keys.`package` in Compile)
))

scalacOptions in Compile := BASIC-OPTIONS-LIST
```

I guess this is relatively simple in terms of lines of code, but not quite so straightforward if one isn't intimately familiar with sbt.