# How to create a separate compile task without a separate config, but different scalacOptions?

Tags: scala, sbt

Departing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633489/sbt-add-new-configuration-to-refine-compile-flags), I want to be able to compile an sbt projects in two different manners, i.e. with different `scalacOptions`. The answer to the duplicate questions explains why introducing another configuration doesn't help because you would also need dedicated sources.

So. But I don't *want* dedicated sources. I want to compile exactly the same sources but with different compiler settings. So I imagine the solution must be to define a *new task* instead that does the compilation. Like

```
val myCompile = taskKey[???]("Compiles my way")

scalacOptions in MyCompile ++= Seq("-elide-below", "1")
```

I would then want the minimum effort to duplicate the default `compile` task with a separate `target` directory, and could that feed than into a `myCompile:assembly`...? How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Use `inspect` to learn the return type of `compile`.

```
> inspect compile
[info] Task: sbt.inc.Analysis
...
```

With this, you should have the following in `build.sbt`:

```
val myCompile = taskKey[sbt.inc.Analysis]("Compiles my way")
myCompile <<= compile in Compile

scalacOptions in myCompile ++= Seq("-elide-below", "1")
```

Comment: That does not pick up the `scalacOptions`

Comment: What scope does `scalacOptions` belong to? I'm explicitly used `scalacOptions in myCompile` in the answer? Do you want to append other scopes' `scalacOptions`?

Comment: I don't know. But `scalacOptions in myCompile` is definitely not picked up by `myCompile`, I have verified this (try adding `"-no-way"` as an option and run `sbt clean myCompile`)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a separate configuration and add

```
sourceDirectory in MyCompile := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value
```

to use `src/main/*` sources, as in [sbt compile tasks with different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520217/sbt-compile-tasks-with-different-options).